# Using a form input to change a JavaScript variable (like a prompt)

Tags: javascript, html

I have put together a text based game using java script. I have it to where when a question is asked, it uses a prompt and pulls up a dialog box where you have to enter your answer. I want to avoid using the dialog box all together and instead have it just print the question on the screen and have a text input box on the page where you can enter your answers. I do not know how to link an html input to my javascript so that it would act like a prompt and change the variable depending on what you enter.

An example of one of the questions is below:

```
var seedcomp = 1
while (seedcomp === 1) {
    var seed = prompt("What kind of potato do you want to be? A RUSSET POTATO, RED POTATO, or SWEET POTATO? Type STOP to quit.").toUpperCase();
        var para = document.createElement("p");
        var node = document.createTextNode("What kind of potato do you want to be? A RUSSET POTATO, RED POTATO, or SWEET POTATO?");
        para.appendChild(node);
        var element = document.getElementById("game");
        element.appendChild(para);
        window.scrollBy(0,1000000);
    switch(seed) {
        case 'RUSSET POTATO' :
            var para = document.createElement("p");
            var node = document.createTextNode("> Hot diggity! You became a Russet Potato!");
            para.appendChild(node);
            var element = document.getElementById("game");
            element.appendChild(para);
            seedcomp = 2
            window.scrollBy(0,1000000);
            break;
        case 'RED POTATO' :
            var para = document.createElement("p");
            var node = document.createTextNode("> Greetings comrade! Welcome to the potatoes of Soviet Socialist Republics! You are a Red Potato.");
            para.appendChild(node);
            var element = document.getElementById("game");
            element.appendChild(para);
            seedcomp = 2
            window.scrollBy(0,1000000);
            break;
        case 'SWEET POTATO' :
            var para = document.createElement("p");
            var node = document.createTextNode("> Hey there sweet thing! You're such a Sweet Potato!");
            para.appendChild(node);
            var element = document.getElementById("game");
            element.appendChild(para);
            seedcomp = 2
            window.scrollBy(0,1000000);
            break;
        case 'STOP' :
            var para = document.createElement("p");
            var node = document.createTextNode("> You ended the game. Click PLAY AGAIN to restart!");
            para.appendChild(node);
            var element = document.getElementById("game");
            element.appendChild(para);
            window.scrollBy(0,1000000);
            throw { name: 'stop', message: 'stop' };
            break;
        default:
            var para = document.createElement("p");
            var node = document.createTextNode("> Make sure you are spelling your answers correctly!");
            para.appendChild(node);
            var element = document.getElementById("game");
            element.appendChild(para);
            window.scrollBy(0,1000000);
    }
}
```

The full game code can be found at [Here](http://www.potatosimulator.com/game.html)

Answer (score 0):

Say you have a simple text input

```
<input type="text" id="input-id" value="">
```

Here's how you can get the input's value with JavaScript

```
var inputValue = document.getElementById('input-id').value;
```

Here is a very basic implementation :

```
<input type="text" id="input-id" value="">
    <button typer="button" onClick="getUserInput();">enter</button>
<script>
function getUserInput() {
    alert( document.getElementById('input-id').value );
}
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sfcdrv68/